# JEST - TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, jestjs

I am using Jest with ES2015, trying to test this component that makes an ajax call (ajax call done with jQuery) on form submit. I'm just trying to mock the value returned and test the value is updated in the component. But I receive this error:

```
  - TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Below is the code for ajax call:

```
accountValidate(name, email).then(this.showMsg);

showMsg(response) {
    if (!response.authenticated) {
      this.setState({msg: response.msg})
    }
  }

accountValidate(name, email) {
    return($.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: `/users/authenticate`,
      headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      data: JSON.stringify({name: name, email: email})
    }));
  }
```

Here is the code for Jest:

```
let testMsg = {msg: 'testing msg'}
const msgResponse = Promise.resolve(testMsg);
accountValidate.mockClear();
accountValidate.mockReturnValue(msgResponse);

      return msgResponse.then(() => {
          console.log('test');
      });
```

Comment: The error implies either `accountValidate` returns `undefined` or `errorResponse` is `undefined`

Comment: but the component is working fine. I am able to make the ajax call, receive data in response and update the component. Only the test fails.

Comment: Is `accountValidate` defined as a function somewhere in your code? It's kind of unclear *where* this code is being pulled from - the `this.setState()` calls make me think this is part of a React component?

Comment: Yes it is defined, you can see above. And yes it is React.js with ES2015

Comment: @sayayin, what is `errorResponse`?

Comment: @MinusFour sorry actually that should be msgResponse, I have updated above.

Answer (score 1):

It's really late but maybe it helps someone.
I would try it like that:

```
let testMsg = {msg: 'testing msg'}

beforeEach(() => {
      (accountValidate: any).mockClear();
      (accountValidate: any).mockReturnValue(
        new Promise(resolve => {
          resolve(testMsg);
        })
      );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi we were getting the same error in the test env we are using the typescript , testing-library/react

I was using node v 14.X but other person was using node 16.X and above they were getting this error. So I updated my node version then able to replicate it on my local.

Then In test file, added the mockcall in the act, as it is affecting in updating the state also

```
act(() => {
  mockAxios.post.mockImplementation(
    async () => Promise.resolve(availabilitySuccessMockData)
  );
});
```